# how to modify a value in .cfg file with libconfig++ and c++

Tags: c++

i have settings.cfg, where is stored some information. For learning purposes i will post here very tiny settings.cfg

```
    application = 
    {
           strings =
           {
                hellostring = "hello";
           }
     };
```

I can read value and put it into varible with, short code, without includes and main

```
       libconfig::Config cfg; 
       std::string  helloVariable = cfg.lookup("application.strings.hellostring");
     std::cout << "Lets cout what we loaded from cfg: " << helloVariable;
     // lets modify helloVariable
     helloVariable = "hello world";

      // how to store modified variable into .cfg, not adding, just modifying 
      // within libconfig++ code, without recreating entire .cfg file with fstream
     return 0;
```

i am using libconfig++ 1.4.9 . 
INFO: I am from cellphone, so code could be broken and not formated well